# Django admin model Inheritance is it possible?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, pinax

Is inheritance possible in admin Models ?

Like For Example consider the following  ,

**File : `models.py`**

```
class AbstractModel ( models.Model ):
    # Meta Information common to all classes
    author = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User , null = False ,related_name="%(class)s_related_author" ) # The user who created 
    editor = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User , null = True,related_name="%(class)s_related_editor" ) # The user who last edited                   
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add  = True) # Create Time
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True) # Modify Time

    class Meta:
                abstract = True


class Topic( AbstractModel ):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = NameMaxLength , unique = True)
    version_number = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    update_frequency = models.IntegerField()
```

A similar inheritance does not seem to produce the correct result when used in `ModelAdmin`

**File : `admin.py`**

```
class Abstract_Admin_Model( admin.ModelAdmin ):
        fields =  ('author' , 'editor' , 'created_at' , 'edited_at')
        readonly_fields = ('author' , 'editor' , 'created_at' , 'edited_at')

        def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
                if not change :
                        obj.author = request.user
                else : 
                        obj.editor = request.user
                obj.save()

class Admin_Topic( Abstract_Admin_Model ):
     fields += ('name' , 'version_number' , 'update_frequency')


admin.site.register( Topic , Admin_Topic )
```

**EDIT**:

I've modified the above model based on suggestions ,

If the `admin.py` is like so , I don't get any error , and the model appears on the admin.

```
class AbstractAdminModel(  admin.ModelAdmin  ):
        pass#fields = ['author' , 'editor' , 'created_at' , 'edited_at']


class Admin_Topic( AbstractAdminModel ):
    pass

admin.site.register( Topic , Admin_Topic )
```

But If i modify it like so

```
class AbstractAdminModel(  admin.ModelAdmin  ):
    fields = ['author' , 'editor' , 'created_at' , 'edited_at']


class Admin_Topic( AbstractAdminModel ):
    pass

admin.site.register( Topic , Admin_Topic )
```

I get the following error :

[image: the Error]

Here is a stack trace [Link](http://pastebin.com/BNn9DaBX)

**Problem :** 
The model does not even appear on the Admin Page

**Extra Info:**

using django 1.2.5 with pinax 0.7.2 , Ubuntu 11.04 , python 2.7.1+

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it is bit to late for you for the answer, but I think others can have similar problem - as I did.

Here is my solution - I am not sure if it is proper, but it works for me and non other from above can do the same (assuming that you want a multitable inheritance (non abstract model), as I do)

```
class SiteEntityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
            (None, {'fields': ['name']}),
    ]


class PhotoAdmin(SiteEntityAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
             ('Photo details', {'fields': ['photo_url', 'description']}),
    ]
    fieldsets.insert(0, SiteEntityAdmin.fieldsets[0])
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible. I think the error you done is to put:

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

in your `Abstract_Admin_Model` class. Try without the `Meta` class.

Comment: It did not make any difference actually

Comment: Are you sure you have your APP in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py? Does it work if try your `Admin_Topic` without inheritance?

Comment: I am Quite sure that the App is installed be cause It worked before I created the Abstract Class and tried to inherit it

Comment: Just a guess, maybe the problem is with the `fields += ...`. Try something along those lines: fields = Abstract_Admin_Model.fields + (...).

Comment: You know, `admin.ModelAdmin` are just a normal python class (not like `Model` class that have a lot of `Meta` works in it), so normal inheritance is working normally (without any use of `Meta` class). If it doesn't work for you, the problem is not in the inheritance (you already inherit from admin.ModelAdmin!) so you need to check for it elsewhere.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033443/python-class-attribute-inheritance. It will explain your error mention in my second comment.

Comment: Nope That hasn't really helped me . I'll modify the question to showcase .

Comment: I did some tests on my side and I can't reproduce your bug (but I'm with Django 1.3). I can help you more if you show me your real code (`Admin_RSSFeed` and al.). In the mean time, something you could try is to set `fields` only in your child class (`Admin_Topic`) and check the results. By the stacktrace it look that the `created_at` field was not created in the form and the validation look for this field? It could be something related to pinax also.

Comment: I'll try out django 1.3 , and get back . I'll also check if i can release the source

Answer (score 3):

To use the parent's class attributes, such as `list_display` or `search_fields` you can do the following:

```
@admin.register(BaseClass)
class BaseClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('field_a', 'field_b')
    search_fields = ('field_a', 'field_b')

@admin.register(ChildClass)
class ChildClassAdmin(BaseClassAdmin):
    def get_list_display(self, request):
        return self.list_display + ('field_c', 'field_d')

    def get_search_fields(self, request):
        return self.search_fields + ('field_c', 'field_d')
```

Similarly you can do that for other attributes like `actions`, `readonly_fields`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
class Admin_Topic( admin.ModelAdmin ):
```

This line controls the inheritance, so it should be:

```
class Admin_Topic( Abstract_Admin_Model ):
```

Also worth noting: you may wish to use `TopicAdmin` rather than `Admin_Topic` to better match the Django convention.

Comment: Sorry , For the accidental mistake in the code , I have edited the code , It doesn't work even then

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but did you restart the web service after making the change?

Comment: :-) , I did , The web service was running while i was editing , I also tried restarting it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

to

```
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        abstract = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The inheritance in your modified admin.py works.
The problem is that you are adding the field 'created_at' to the admin (Admin_RSSFeed),
but it does not exist on the model (probably named RSSFeed?).
(At least that is what the error screenshot tries to tell you.)