# Register abstract model in admin django 1.6

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

After searching a while i didn't find any clear solution

**File: models.py**

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Company(BaseModel):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

**File: models.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Company

class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

I tried the solution here: [Django admin model Inheritance is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376102/django-admin-model-inheritance-is-it-possible?lq=1) but nothing works, and the admin is only showing the company_name

Comment: have you tried just `admin.site.register(Company)`? otherwise you need an inner `class Meta: model = Company` inside the admin class you create (this is general Django admin stuff, not specific to abstract models, which should just work as intended)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why those fields are not being showed in the admin, is because of the `auto_now` and `auto_now`. What you need to do is adde them explicitly as read-only fields:

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Company

class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('created_date', 'modified_date')

admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

Comment: This is the exactly answer! Thanks

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the pointer. I'm using a custom abstract base class along with `TimeStampedModel` and `AuthStampedModel` and I couldn't figure out how to get fields like `created` or `created_by` to show up!