# Django 1.11 adding an abstract base model to admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a base model with abstract=True.
    # models.py

```
class Media(models.Model):          
    title = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length=200)
    excerpt = RichTextField(config_name = 'extralight', blank=True, null=True)  

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Model image, sound and document are subclasses of media model. I want to get all the list of media models.

What is the best way of adding abstract media model to django admin?

Comment: There's an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715667/django-admin-for-abstract-base-class

Answer (score 0):

```
subclass  = Media.__subclasses__()
```

this will return all subclasses of Media

**Abstract model can not use directly to admin.**

you have to inherit Media model to another model and create that model without abstract then you can add subclass model to django admin.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to make Media the main Model

then create proxy models for Image, Sound and Document.

This way you have all the information in one database table yourapp_media, and you can have One or Three Admin.

```
from model_utils.managers import QueryManager
class Media(models.Model):          
    title = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length=200)
    content_type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=settings.CONTENT_TYPE,editable=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Media, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.content_type = self.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE

class Image(Media):
    DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = settings.IMAGE_TYPE
    objects = QueryManager(content_type=settings.IMAGE_TYPE)
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class Sound(Media):
    DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = settings.SOUND_TYPE
    objects = QueryManager(content_type=settings.SOUND_TYPE)
    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class Document(Media):
    DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = settings.DOCUMENT_TYPE
    objects = QueryManager(content_type=settings.DOCUMENT_TYPE)
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

In the admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Media, MediaAdmin)
admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
admin.site.register(Sound, SoundAdmin)
admin.site.register(Document, DocumentAdmin)
```